# Javascript resize function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user is using a mobile phone that time only that click event want work otherwise dont want to work

```js
const domain = document.getElementById("domainshow");
const host = document.getElementById("hostingshow");
const togone = document.getElementById("mobiletoggleone");
const togtwo = document.getElementById("mobiletogglesec");

if (togone.style.display === 'block' && togtwo.style.display === 'block') {
  togone.style.display = 'none';
  togtwo.style.display = 'none';
}

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 1100) {
    domain.addEventListener('click', () => {
      togone.style.display = 'block';
      togtwo.style.display = 'none';
    });

    host.addEventListener('click', () => {
      togtwo.style.display = 'block';
      togone.style.display = 'none';
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Aside from the issue - you shouldn't be using JS to detect screen resolution and amending the UI accordingly. This is *exactly* what [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries) should be used for

Comment: I didn't check, but I don't think you get a `resize` even when the page first loads, only when... well... when the window **re**sizes.   Hook into the load event instead.

Comment: maybe.. iam struck in this problem now